# setup Python/Django on subdirectory using apache in windows

Tags: python, django, apache

I am trying to setup Django Site on suburl like `www.example.com/django` , my apache settings are as follows :

```
<Location "/">
        SetHandler python-program
        PythonPath "[r'path to packages '] + sys.path"
        PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
        SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE settings
        PythonDebug On
    </Location>
```

What parameter do I have to add here to make it accessible at `www.example.com/django` instead of `www.example.com`

Comment: Instead of : `<Location "/">` try `<Location "/django">`

Comment: You should under no circumstances be using modpython. That is deprecated and unsupported. Use mod_wsgi instead.

Comment: @Liarez I ahve tried that but then it is taking Django as site url not url with domain means www.example.com/domain must act as complete domain.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes I know and I have did the same thing with mod_wsgi and that is working fin e but rt now my requirement is with modpython , so any solution ?

Comment: @DanielRoseman found the solution , need to add PythonOption django.root /django in settings

Answer (score 0):

Need to add PythonOption django.root /django in apache settings so the complete code will be :

```
<Location "/django/">
        SetHandler python-program
        PythonPath "[r'path to packages '] + sys.path"
        PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
        SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE settings
        PythonDebug On
        PythonOption django.root /django
    </Location>
```